# How to pass an object to a Method using FitNesse and Slim

Tags: c#, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I'm using FitNesse and SLIM and I would like to be able to pass an object to a method and can't seem to find out how? How do you do this using SLIM?

So for example I want to build a call object

```
!|FitTesting.MakeCall                             |
|ANI       |Call Type|Call Id|Call Key No| Data|
|4403951403|2        |2000   |8000       |5000 |
```

I want to store that object in a symbol or variable name `CallObject`

Then I want to use that object in the Start Call method.

```
|script | FitTesting.PracticeCallTestFixture|
|Initialize Call Fixture|
|Start Call|<<With Call Object>>
|check|Check For Call|true|
|Finalize Phone Desktop|
```

I tried to use a dictionary but got the following exception

```
EXCEPTION_:fitSharp.Machine.Exception.ParseException1[System.String]: Parse parameter 1 for 'UpdateECCData' type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[System.String,System.String] failed. ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
   at fitSharp.Machine.Model.BranchList1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at fitSharp.Slim.Operators.ParseDictionary.Parse(Type type, TypedValue instance, Tree1 parameters)
   at fitSharp.Machine.Engine.ProcessorBase2.<>c__DisplayClass11.<>c__DisplayClass13.<Parse>b__10(ParseOperator1 o)
   at fitSharp.Machine.Engine.ProcessorBase2.<>c__DisplayClass11.<Parse>b__e(OperationLogging logging)
   at fitSharp.Machine.Engine.ProcessorBase2.DoLoggedOperation[R](String startMessage, Func2 operation)
   at fitSharp.Machine.Engine.ParameterList1.ParseParameterValue(RuntimeMember member, TypedValue instance, Tree1 parameter, Int32 parameterIndex)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at fitSharp.Machine.Engine.ParameterList1.ParseParameterValue(RuntimeMember member, TypedValue instance, Tree1 parameter, Int32 parameterIndex)
   at fitSharp.Machine.Engine.ParameterList1.<>c_DisplayClass1.b_0(List1 parameterList, Tree1 parameter)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Aggregate[TSource,TAccumulate](IEnumerable1 source, TAccumulate seed, Func3 func)
   at fitSharp.Machine.Engine.ParameterList1.GetParameterList(TypedValue instance, Tree1 parameters, RuntimeMember member)
   at fitSharp.Machine.Engine.InvokeDefault2.Invoke(TypedValue instance, String memberName, Tree1 parameters)
   at fitSharp.Slim.Operators.InvokeLibrary.Invoke(TypedValue instance, String memberName, Tree1 parameters)
   at fitSharp.Machine.Engine.ProcessorBase2.<>c_DisplayClass18.<>c_DisplayClass1a.b_17(InvokeOperator1 o)
   at fitSharp.Machine.Engine.ProcessorBase2.<>c_DisplayClass18.b_15(OperationLogging logging)
   at fitSharp.Machine.Engine.ProcessorBase2.DoLoggedOperation[R](String startMessage, Func2 operation)
   at fitSharp.Slim.Operators.InvokeInstructionBase.InvokeMember(Tree1 parameters, Int32 memberIndex)
   at fitSharp.Slim.Operators.ExecuteCall.ExecuteOperation(Tree1 parameters)
   at fitSharp.Slim.Operators.InvokeInstructionBase.Invoke(TypedValue instance, String memberName, Tree`1 parameters)
```

Here is the fit markup

```
!|FitTestingConnectCTI.MakeCall                                                                |
|ANI       |Call Type|Router Call Key Id|Router Call Key Day|Update ECC Data                   |
|4403951403|2        |2000              |5000               |!{ANI:4403951403,StateAbbr:OH}    |
```

Here is my method call

```
   public void UpdateECCData(Dictionary<string,string> eccDictionary)
    {
        if (eccDictionary != null)
        {
            if (eccDictionary.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair in eccDictionary)
                {
                    ECCData.Add(keyValuePair.Key,keyValuePair.Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for helping me with the editing.

Comment: Is there a solution to this problem by now?

Answer (score 0):

For c# I don't know. For Java you could either register a [custom type](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.SliM.CustomTypes), or rewrite the method to accept a Hashtable (i.e. Dictionary) and use the [Hash widget](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.MarkupHashTable).

Comment: Thanks do you have any examples of this in C#? I've tried to do the dictionary and hashtable with no success.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass the parameter in Fitnesse in Json format, then implement a method in your code that converts from json to Dictionnary.
What I did - using Java -  is the following:

1. Pass a string in Fitnesse having jsonFormat. For example `{"username":"xxx", "password":"yyy"}`
2. In the code the method does the following:

   *`public void login(String credentials){
    Map<String,String> cred = (Map<String, String>)JSONValue.parse(credentials);
    }`*

In this case you will be only dealing with json on the Fitnesse side. u just need to change the way of converting json to map (json to dictionary in C#)
Hope this helps a bit.